# Find all even number in array in purescript but getting type mismatch error

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I am solving a problem in which I have to count all the even numbers in an array in purescript. I have written down code but I am facing type mismatch error.

```
import Data.Array (null)
import Data.Array.Partial (tail,head)
import Partial.Unsafe (unsafePartial)
import Math

iseven :: Int -> Boolean
iseven a = mod a 2 == 0


len :: forall a. Array a -> Int
len arr =
  if null arr
  then 0
  else
    if iseven unsafePartial head arr
      then 1 + len (unsafePartial tail arr)
      else len (unsafePartial tail arr)
```

But I am getting an error.

```
Error found:
in module $PSCI
at :6:18 - 6:40 (line 6, column 18 - line 6, column 40)

  Could not match type

    a1

  with type

    Int


while checking that type t0
  is at least as general as type Int
while checking that expression (unsafePartial head) arr
  has type Int
in binding group len

where a1 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
      t0 is an unknown type
```

I am new to purescript so I am not able to understand the error.

Comment: You have not posted your actual code. The error message could not have resulted from the code you posted. Please double check and amend.

Comment: The line 6 is from len function means considering it at line 1

Comment: No, you're definitely not. Specifically, the line `iseven unsafePartial head arr` is incorrect. Judging by the error you get, that line probably looks something like `iseven (unsafePartial head arr)`. Please double check.

Comment: Here is link to it https://ibb.co/rMQWgn8

Comment: Your screenshot confirms exactly what I've been saying: your actual code is `iseven (unsafePartial head arr)`, which is not what you posted in the question.

Comment: But how to solve it ?

Comment: @K.Bakshi Can I ask if you avoiding `Array` related utils on purpose? I mean: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-arrays/4.0.1/docs/Data.Array .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `unsafePartial head arr`, that means "apply function `unsafePartial` to two arguments, first argument `head` and second argument `arr`, but this is not what you want to do.

What you want to do is first calculate `head arr`, and only then apply `unsafePartial` to the result of that.

To achieve this, use parentheses:

```
unsafePartial (head arr)
```

Or the `$` operator:

```
unsafePartial $ head arr
```

---

After you have fixed that, the next error you're getting is about what `iseven` expects as argument and what you're passing to it. The signature of `len` says `forall a. Array a ->`, which means "*I will work with arrays of any type*", but in reality it's trying to pass an element of that array to `iseven`, which expects an `Int`. So your function promised to work with anything, but actually wants `Int`.

To fix, make the signature tell the truth: the function wants an array of `Int`s:

```
len :: Array Int -> Int
```

Comment: That's because you're now first calculating `iseven unsafePartial`, then calculating `head arr`, and then applying the former to the latter. Do this: `iseven (unsafePartial $ head arr)`. Or this: `iseven $ unsafePartial $ head arr`. And _please_ learn how basic syntax works first.

Comment: https://ibb.co/QnGnp57 same error. The code is working explicitly correct but when I am writing it in function its giving error.

Comment: You're now having a different error. I have amended the answer to address it, but this is the last time. Please read tutorials and examples first, then try to reason about your code on your own.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am new to purescript and I am not able to find proper documents or tutorials so. Also there are very few examples so its little bit tough.